# How to respond with format.pdf in rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, wicked-pdf

Im trying to use jquery to get a controller action which shows a pdf page. Before the javascript way, the rails way worked:

**Show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Get PDF", client_path(@client.id, format: :pdf) %>
```

The issue is, I need some params that I get from javascript so a work around was to use ajax to make the request:

**js:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/clients/" + clientId + ".pdf",
  type: 'POST', // Ive also tried GET and created a post route in routes.rb
  data: { //...
  },
  success: function(data, xhr) {
    //...
    console.log('Success.....');
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("Error....")
  }

});
```

**Controller:**

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json

def show
   respond_with do |format|
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "demopdf",
               template: "clients/show.pdf.html.erb",
               locals: {:client => @client}
      end
    end
end
```

If I click my rails button, I get the pdf view but not so with a normal button with a button click function. How to do this with ajax? I got the success log but that's it.

**EDIT:**

How to get `Bar` to my controller? I need to have `Bar` in my pdf?

**show.html.erb:**

```
<p id="foo"></p>
```

**js:**

```
$("#foo").text("Bar");
```

So basically I need to pass few params in:

```
<%= link_to "Get PDF", client_path(@client.id, format: :pdf) %>
```

Comment: What parameter do you need to pass on button click?

Comment: I have few text that is filled with javascript ie: `<h1 id="foo"></h1>` and the js: `$("#foo").text("Bar");` So I need to pass also `Bar` to the controller so I thought ajax would be best?

Comment: Did you try adding remote to `link_to`, that should work. for e.g: `<%= link_to "Get PDF", client_path(@client.id, format: :pdf, remote: true) %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the parameters, you can do so by adding params in your route code.

`<%= link_to "Get PDF", client_path(@client.id, format: :pdf, params1: 'some param', params2: 'other param2' ...) %>`

If you need to use the ajax for the link, the add 
`remote: true` in there as well.